# Row not getting deleted from json

Tags: javascript, json

Below is my Json data:-

```
var oData = {
  rows: [
    {
      name:"nick",
      t_keyword: [
        { keyword: "SAP CRM" },
        { keyword: "ERP"},
        { keyword: "SAP"},
        { keyword: "JAM"},
        { keyword: "TECH"},
        { keyword: "fly"},
      ]
    },              
  ]
};
```

when I use splice(2, 0) it dosen't deletes anything.
Any idea why row is not getting deleted?

Comment: That isn't JSON, it is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "delete" keyword if you want to delete record in the object. for example

```
delete(oData.rows[0].t_keyword[0]);
```

also you can use

```
oData.rows[0].t_keyword.splice(0, 2);
```

or

```
oData.rows[0].t_keyword.pop();
```

to remove last element from array

Comment: That's an array. Using `delete` will leave a blank space. That is usually undesirable.

Comment: splice(fromWhichIndexStart, howManyElementsRemoveFromThatIndex)

Comment: if is use oData.rows[0].t_keyword.splice(0 ,2) then i think it will delete 2 elements from location 0 that is 0,1 elements. what i want is to delete directly the second element ....

Comment: my code removes first two elements. if you want to remove first element just use 0, 1

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation for splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> `array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])`

The second argument is the number of items to delete. If you set it to zero then zero items will be deleted.

Comment: It would help if you showed us exactly how you are using `splice` and how you are determining that it has no effect.